# How can I make a query by a Django foreignkey description?

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-orm

if i have this code

```
class Father(models.Model):
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
    Code        = models.IntegerField(max_length=2, unique=True)
    def __unicode__(self):
        return "%s (%s)" % (self.Description, self.Code)

class Son(models.Model):
    Father = models.ForeignKey(Father)
    Description = models.CharField(max_length=50)
```

And I want to create a filter by the select box shown to the user.

Assuming that I have a record in  Father like:

```
  # |  Description | Code
--------------------------
  1 | Fred Nichols | 100
```

In the ForeignKey field should have a HTML content like:

```
<option value="1">Fred NIchols (100)</option>
```

if I try to query by the field in the son model:

```
Son.objects.filter(Father__Contains="Fred")
```

I get an error. In the documentation of Django the nearest option should be something like:

```
Son.objects.filter(Father__Description__contains="Fred")
```

or for any of the columns data

```
Son.objects.filter(Q(Father__Description__contains="Fred") | Q(Father__Code__Contains="Fred") )
```

I'd like to make something the most similar to the user info shown.

How could I make a query that could do that?

Comment: Your question isn't clear. What are you trying to do? That last line of code should fetch any son that's father FK's description or code contains "Fred".

Comment: If the user try to search something like "(" it should be able to find all the records. The search should work as if it were the string in the ForeignKey field

Comment: What fields does it need to search across?

Comment: I guess he's asking how to filter based on the return value of `__unicode__`.

Comment: And that's [not possible](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property) (duplicate question)

Comment: No that's not, but if @MikeVelazco defines the fields he wants to search, it is possible to build the functionality he actually needs.

Comment: @schillingt That would be pretty cumbersome, `save` would've had to be altered to update the field when either `Description` or `Code` were changed.

Answer (score 0):

In single step u could do this :

```
Son.objects.filter(father__Description__contains="Fred")
```

you were doing it right the only thing that was wrong is :

*the referencing entity Father should be lowercase name of the model*

[reference](http://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/topics/db/queries/#lookups-that-span-relationships)