# Change Django AbstractUser model fields

Tags: python, django

Given this simple user model:

```
class User(AbstractUser):
    height = models.IntegerField(default=0)
    # active= models.CharField(db_column='is_active') ??? How
```

The `is_active` is a field  in `AbstractUser` but I want to refer to it as `active`. Using the same `db_column` gives the following error:

> Field 'active' has column name 'is_active' that is used by another
>   field. HINT: Specify a 'db_column' for the field.

How can this be accomplished?

Comment: What about [through a property](http://www.stavros.io/posts/how-replace-django-model-field-property/)?

Comment: @danihp, property is not [filterable](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property).