# Django: Filtering querysets using method rather than attributes?

Tags: python, django, django-queryset

I'm trying to get all loyal clients in my Django app. For this, I'm trying to filter a queryset using a method, rather than an attribute, and I don't know how to do this.
**EDIT** : using Kedar advice, I tried to to this with `@property` decorator

```
class Client(models.Model):

    @property
    def is_loyal(self):
        # ...
        # Return True or False

    @classmethod
    def get_loyal_clients_since(cls):

        # Method #1: works but clearly a workaround
        base_clients = cls.some_method_to_retrieve_special_clients()
        clients_list = [c.pk for c in base_clients if c.is_loyal()]
        clients = cls.objects.filter(pk__in=clients_list)

        # Method #2: does not work
        clients = cls.some_method_to_retrieve_special_clients() \
                  .filter(is_loyal=True)
```

Error: `Cannot resolve keyword 'is_loyal' into field.`

Comment: you can make `is_loyal` a property (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/glossary/#term-property). Then the filtering should work.

Comment: Very good idea, but it does not seem to work (`Cannot resolve keyword 'is_loyal' into field.`)

Comment: Wouldn't a Manager for the "loyal" clients just do that ? I'm not that sure what you are looking for, but as Managers return querysets, you would be able to filter afterwards. See https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.7/topics/db/managers/

Comment: If I use a manager to filter loyal clients THEN calling my `some_method()` it will be definitely slower. I really need to call `some_method()` first, then get the loyal ones then. :(

Comment: @kedar? You sure it works that way? Just found out on this thread it seems to be impossible: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property

Comment: My mistake, I am checking the property when iterating, can't filter. You are correct.

Comment: if you need to filter on this you need to be able to do it in an SQL query... you need to be able to express the logic of `is_loyal` property in terms of fields in the db... if you can do that it may be possible in Django ORM