# django querset filter foreign key select first record

Tags: django, django-queryset, foreign-key-relationship

I have a History model like below

```
class History(models.Model):

    class Meta:
        app_label = 'subscription'
        ordering = ['-start_datetime']

    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription, related_name='history')

    FREE = 'free'
    Premium = 'premium'
    SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_CHOICES = ((FREE, 'Free'), (Premium, 'Premium'),)
    name = models.CharField(max_length=32, choices=SUBSCRIPTION_TYPE_CHOICES, default=FREE)

    start_datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    cancelled_datetime = models.DateTimeField(blank=True, null=True)
```

Now i have a queryset filtering like below

```
users = get_user_model().objects.all()
queryset = users.exclude(subscription__history__end_datetime__lt=timezone.now())
```

The issue is that in the exclude above it is checking end_datetime for all the rows for a particular history object. But i only want to compare it with first row of history object.

Below is how a particular history object looks like. So i want to write a queryset filter which can do datetime comparison on first row only.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

You could use a [Model Manager method](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/managers/#adding-extra-manager-methods) for this. The documentation isn't all that descriptive, but you could do something along the lines of:

```
class SubscriptionManager(models.Manager):
    def my_filter(self):
        # You'd want to make this a smaller query most likely
        subscriptions = Subscription.objects.all()
        results = []

        for subscription in subscriptions:
            sub_history = subscription.history_set.first()  
            if sub_history.end_datetime > timezone.now:
                results.append(subscription)

        return results


class History(models.Model):
    subscription = models.ForeignKey(Subscription)
    end_datetime = models.DateTimeField(db_index=True, blank=True, null=True)
    objects = SubscriptionManager()
```

Then: `queryset = Subscription.objects().my_filter()`

Not a copy-pastable answer, but shows the use of Managers. Given the specificity of what you're looking for, I don't think there's a way to get it just via the plain `filter()` and `exclude()`.

Without knowing what your end goal here is, it's hard to say whether this is feasible, but have you considered adding a property to the subscription model that indicates whatever you're looking for? For example, if you're trying to get everyone who has a subscription that's ending:

```
class Subscription(models.Model):
    @property
    def ending(self):
        if self.end_datetime > timezone.now:
            return True
        else:
            return False
```

Then in your code: `queryset = users.filter(subscription_ending=True)`

Comment: Custom manager is overkill and filter by property is not possible as per http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property

Answer (score 0):

I have tried django's all king of expressions([aggregate](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.10/topics/db/aggregation/), [query](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/), [conditional](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/conditional-expressions/)) but was unable to solve the problem so i went with [RawSQL](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/1.8/ref/models/expressions/#raw-sql-expressions) and it solved the problem.

I have used the below SQL to select the first row and then compare the end_datetime

```sql
SELECT (end_datetime > %s OR end_datetime IS NULL) AS result 
FROM subscription_history 
ORDER BY start_datetime DESC 
LIMIT 1;
```

I will select my answer as accepted if not found a solution with queryset filter chaining in next 2 days.