# django summing over values or function values

Tags: django, django-models, django-views

In a django-project I have the following line:

```
person_lista = Personal.objects.annotate(tjgtid=Sum('personyear__tjgtim'))
```

When the class PersonYear contained the variable

```
tjgtim = models.FloatField(default=0)
```

this worked fine. But now I have changed it so that it is a function:

```
def tjgtim:
    return .....
```

and now it does not work. Why is that? What should I do differently?

Thanks in advance,
-anders

Comment: The error is 'Cannot resolve keyword 'tjgtim' into field'

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Filter by property](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property)

Comment: Are you using the same name for the field and the function? That will probably cause errors.