# Django filter on calculated field when calculated field returns the value based on combination of two model fields

Tags: django, django-filter

How to filter on calculated field whose values can be decided based on combination of two model fields in the same Model?

**Models.py**

```
class Job(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def _get_job_status(self):
        if self.is_complete is False and self.expiry_time >= now:
            return "active"
        elif self.is_complete is False and self.expiry_time < now:
            return "expired"
        else:
            return "complete"

    job_status = property(_get_job_status)
```

I want to filter on job_status field, which can have 3 values active, expired or complete. I can not add job_status field directly in the filter fields, so how to filter on it?

**Update1**

According to the responses, my above solution is not correct. So, If I try to solve this issue by creating two different filters say **is_complete** and **is_expired**, but still I am not finding the way to specify the queryset for is_complete BooleanFilter. My is_complete = True should give result for the condition **(is_complete is False and expiry_time >= now)** and Is_complete = False should give result for the condition **(is_complete is False and expiry_time < now)** How can I write this query?

**filters.py**

```
class JobStatusFilter(FilterSet):
    is_active = filters.BooleanFilter(name="is_complete")

    class Meta:
        model = Job
        fields = ('is_complete',)
```

Comment: You cannot do this with filter() directly. Check this question: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property

Comment: I have updates the question. Please check **Update1**

Answer (score 0):

I would recommend doing the following with class methods. Don't get me wrong it isn't implementing the filter function directly, but this is the most pythonic work around possible. All you would have to do now is run `Job.filter_job_status('active', queryset or None)` to get all jobs that are in active state. The main benefit to doing it like this is for the sake of repeating the same query steps all over the place. This will return a queryset that way all you have to do past this is filter for more data if need be.

```
# models.py
class Job(models.Model):
    start_time = models.DateTimeField(auto_now_add=True)
    end_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    expiry_time = models.DateTimeField(null=True)
    is_complete = models.BooleanField(default=True)

    def _get_job_status(self):
        if self.is_complete is False and self.expiry_time >= now:
            return "active"
        elif self.is_complete is False and self.expiry_time < now:
            return "expired"
        else:
            return "complete"

    # Not sure if it matters but the property might need to be above the 
    # class method.
    job_status = property(_get_job_status)

    # Might be a bit database heavy but it will work for 99.9999% of 
    # situations.
    @classmethod
    def filter_job_status(cls, status, queryset=None):
        job_matches = []
        if queryset is None:
            queryset = cls.objects.all()
        assert queryset.model is cls, \
            "filter job status only accepts Job querysets."
        for job in queryset:
            if status in job.job_status:
                job_matches.append(job.pk)
        # return queryset to allow more filtering if needed
        return cls.objects.filter(pk__in=job_matches)
```

Comment: Unfortunately the filter set will not work since it is still querying the database. It will essentially be called in about the same way as my function. You could create it with the same concept of passing a queryset to it rather than gathering all. I'll update my answer for that.

Comment: I updated the answer to fix a couple syntax problems (typed from my phone). Let me know if you still have questions.