# Django-filter: filtering by model property

Tags: django, properties, django-queryset, django-filter

I read on [several](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property) [places](https://github.com/carltongibson/django-filter/issues/889) that it is not possible to filter Django querysets using properties because Django ORM would have no idea how to convert those into SQL.

However, once the data are fetched and loaded into memory, it *shall* be possible to filter them in Python using those properties.

And my question: is there any library that allows the querysets to be filtered by properties in memory? And if not, how exactly must the querysets be tampered with so that this becomes possible? And how to include `django-filter` into this?

Answer (score 3):

Have you got difficult property or not?
If not you can rewrite it to queryset like this:

```py
from django.db import models

class UserQueryset(models.Manager):

    def get_queryset(self):

        return super().get_queryset().annotate(
            has_profile=models.Exists(Profile.objects.filter(user_id=models.OuterRef('id')))
        )

class User(models.Model):
    objects = UserQueryset


class Profile(models.Model):
    user = models.OneToOneField(User, related_name='profile')


# When you want to filter by has profile just use it like has field has profile

user_with_profiles = User.objects.filter(has_profile=True)
```

Maybe it is not what you want, but it can help you in some cases

Comment: I would like to have a general API for all kinds of properties so yes, I might have difficult ones.

Comment: @karloss, I would suggest that the generic API is Django ORM itself.  Almost every time you push a filter to the Database through the Django ORM, it is going to be faster than loading up that data and then filtering it yourself in python.  Not because python is too slow, but because you're pulling more data out of the database instead of filtering it inside the database.  Writing a custom `django_filters.Filter` for odd inferred properties isn't that bad.

Comment: @karloss, you could also generate annotations and filters on the fly.  Create new filters and then filterset using [Metaclasses](https://realpython.com/python-metaclasses/).  I've done this to great effect with Django Rest Framework in order to let the client trim down the number of fields coming back to itself from the server backend.

Answer (score 1):

`django-filter` wants and assumes that you are using querysets.  Once you take a queryset and change it into a `list`, then whatever is downstream needs to be able to handle just a `list` or just iterate through the list, which is no longer a queryset.

If you have a `django_filters.FilterSet` like:

```
class FooFilterset(django_filters.FilterSet):
    bar = django_filters.Filter('updated', lookup_expr='exact')
    my_property_filter = MyPropertyFilter('property')
    class Meta:
        model = Foo
        fields = ('bar',  'my_property_filter')
```

then you can write `MyPropertyFilter` like:

```
class MyPropertyFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        return [row for row in qs if row.baz == value]
```

At this point, anything downstream of `MyProperteyFilter` will have a list.

*Note: I believe the order of `fields` should have your custom filter, `MyPropertyFilter` last, because then it will always be processed after the normal queryset filters.*

---

So, you have just broken the "queryset" API, for certain values of broken.  At this point, you'll have to work through the errors of whatever is downstream.  If whatever is after the `FilterSet` requires a `.count` member, you can change `MyPropertyFilter` like:

```
class MyPropertyFilter(django_filters.Filter):
    def filter(self, qs, value):
        result = [row for row in qs if row.baz == value]
        result.count = len(result)
        return result
```

You're in uncharted territory, and you'll have to hack your way through.

Anyways, I've done this before and it isn't horrible.  Just take the errors as they come.

Comment: Isn't it better to return a QuerySet instead of a list?

Comment: Sure it's better to return a queryset.  But you're saying that you can't.  If you cannot do the filtering on the database, then you must do the filtering afterwards.  A queryset is something that can absolutely be executed on a database. If you can change your property to somehow be executed on the database, then you avoid this altogether.  If, however, you must do filtering in actual python, then you  have violated the essence of a queryset and it is no longer a queryset.

Comment: Sorry, maybe I did not express myself well. Can I do something like `return QuerySet([row for row in qs if row.baz ==value])` so that it has all the methods like `.count`, `.filter` and so on? Of course, they would all just work in-memory and won't hit the database at all, or at least this is my idea. May I get this somehow to work?

Comment: There isn't a default way to change `list` back into a `QuerySet`.  `.count` is easy in the list case, but what about `.filter()` ? Django ORM doesn't know how to do filtering on a `list`, it only does filtering on the database.  Anyways, each part of the `QuerySet` API, _that your downstream code is using_, will need to be implemented.  If you order the filters correctly, you may be fine with just putting your `QuerySet` -> `list` filter at the end of the order of `fields`.

Answer (score 1):

Since filtering by non-field attributes such as `property` inevitably converts the `QuerySet` to `list` (or similar), I like to postpone it and do the filtering on `object_list` in `get_context_data` method. To keep the filtering logic inside the `filterset` class, I use a simple trick. I've defined a `decorator`

```
def attr_filter(func):

    def wrapper(self, queryset, name, value, force=False, *args, **kwargs):
        if force:
            return func(self, queryset, name, value, *args, **kwargs)
        else:
            return queryset
    return wrapper
```

which is used on `django-filter` non-field filtering methods. Thanks to this decorator, the filtering basically does nothing (or skips) the non-field filtering methods (because of `force=False` default value).

Next, I defined a `Mixin` to be used in the `view` class.

```
    class FilterByAttrsMixin:
    
        def get_context_data(self, **kwargs):
            context = super().get_context_data(**kwargs)
            filtered_list = self.filter_qs_by_attributes(self.object_list, self.filterset)
            context.update({
                'object_list': filtered_list,
            })
            return context
    
        def filter_qs_by_attributes(self, queryset, filterset_instance):
            if hasattr(filterset_instance.form, 'cleaned_data'):
                for field_name in filter_instance.filters:
                    method_name = f'attr_filter_{field_name}'
                    if hasattr(filterset_instance, method_name):
                        value = filterset_instance.form.cleaned_data[field_name]
                        if value:
                            queryset = getattr(filterset_instance, filter_method_name)(queryset, field_name, value, force=True)
            return queryset
```

It basically just returns to your `filterset` and runs all methods called `attr_filter_<field_name>`, this time with `force=True`.

**In summary, you need to:**

- Inherit the `FilterByAttrsMixin` in your `view` class
- call your filtering method `attr_filter_<field_name>`
- use `attr_filter` decorator on the filtering method

**Simple example** (given that I have `model` called `MyModel` with `property` called `is_static` that I want to filter by:

model:

```
class MyModel(models.Model):
    ...

@property
def is_static(self):
    ...
```

view:

```
class MyFilterView(FilterByAttrsMixin, django_filters.views.FilterView):
    ...
    filterset_class = MyFiltersetClass
    ...
```

filter:

```
class MyFiltersetClass(django_filters.FilterSet):
    is_static = django_filters.BooleanFilter(
        method='attr_filter_is_static',
    )

    class Meta:
        model = MyModel
        fields = [...]

    @attr_filter
    def attr_filter_is_static(self, queryset, name, value):
        return [instance for instance in queryset if instance.is_static]
```

Answer (score 1):

Take a look at [django-property-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-property-filter/) package. This is an extension to [django-filter](https://pypi.org/project/django-filter/) and provides functionality to filter querysets by class properties.

Short example from the documentation:

```
from django_property_filter import PropertyNumberFilter, PropertyFilterSet

class BookFilterSet(PropertyFilterSet):
    prop_number = PropertyNumberFilter(field_name='discounted_price', lookup_expr='gte')

    class Meta:
        model = NumberClass
        fields = ['prop_number']
```