# Django admin list_filter on custom model function

Tags: python-3.x, django, django-models, django-admin

In my django model i create a custom function for retrive a data from another model like this:

```
class UserProfile(models.Model):
    ...

    def card_type(self):
        if self.user:
            return a_cards.objects.get(c_user = self.user.id).c_type
        return "-"

    card_type.allow_tags = True
    card_type.short_description = "Card Type"
```

then in my admin i do:

```
list_display = ('u_sname', 'u_name','user_link', 'card_type', ...
```

all was done, but if i try to add in django admin a possibility to filter (at the right side) for that kind of data i use:

```
list_filter = ('card_type',)
```

but i get:

> ERRORS:
> <class 'agenti.admin.UserAdmin'>: (admin.E116) The value of 'list_filter[1]' refers to 'card_type', which does not refer to a Field.

I am not trying to filter directly from my model data, i would django Admin display at the right side the possibility to filter from these  method data.

So many thanks in advance

Comment: Django can't do the filtering based on a method/property, which defined in the model level. This is because the filtering process is carried out in the SQL/DB level, not python-level

Comment: This is the same for the whole Django framework, including Django admin.

Comment: One possible solution is to create a custom manager or annotated QuerySet ([see this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/36996962/8283848)) to ***"replicate your method logic"*** and use the filter. This time, you may need to use the [**`get_filter()`**](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/stable/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin.get_list_filter) method of the Django Model Admin