# Django: Add property condition for another property

Tags: python, django, function, model, properties

For a property, I can't manage to filter a Queryset with another property.
I want that if "father" has "Star" in "True", "star_descendant" returns "father".

I have this error: Exception Value: 'QuerySet' object has no attribute 'star'.
How to fix it?

My code :

```
    @property
    def star(self):
        if Evenements.objects.filter(eventtype=93).filter(xrefindividuproprio=self):
            return True
        return False

    @property
    def star_descendant(self):
        father = Individus.objects.filter(codeid=self.xrefpere_id)
        mother = Individus.objects.filter(codeid=self.xrefmere_id)
        if father.star == True:
            return father
```

Comment: Please share your models.

Answer (score 0):

In your function, "father" and "mother" are querysets. "star" is a property of an object. You must to get an object. Queryset has no attribute "star".

```
if Individus.objects.filter(codeid=self.xrefpere_id).count() > 0:
    father = Individus.objects.filter(codeid=self.xrefpere_id).first()
    if father.star == True:
        return father
```

Or, if `codeid` is an unique field, then: `father = Individus.objects.get(codeid=self.xrefpere_id)`

Comment: Thanks you for your answer.
Can I get a queryset of all items with "star" in property for example?

Comment: No, you don't. Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property