# Is there a way to copy annotations from one Django queryset to another?

Tags: django, postgresql

I am currently trying to overcome the challenge of ordering a queryset in Django with foreign key attributes.

As you may know this can have unintended results with duplicate entries. The other option is to specify an ordering on the same queryset but to avoid duplicates but this leads to `SELECT DISTINCT ON expressions must match initial ORDER BY expressions`

So I resorted to creating another queryset to filter the id's in an already annotated queryset so i can get a fresh queryset with which can be ordered by what is needed in the end. I also tried to copy the annotations present on one queryset to another using the *queryset.query.annotations* ValueDict but it failed.

Here is the scenario:

## Models

```py
class Home(models.Model):
  street=models.CharField(...)
  city=models.CharField(...)
  
class Person(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(...)
  home=models.ForeignKey(Home,...)
```

## Objective

- Get a  of *Person* queryset ordered by the *street*, *city* combination in one string (Concatenation).

## Attempt

```py
queryset=Person.objects.annotate(addr=Concat('home__street', Value(' '), 'home__city'))

queryset.filter(...).order_by('addr').distinct('pk')
# Failed with an error
```

## Attempt 2 (filter by pks on original )

```py
Person.objects.filter(pk__in=\
queryset.filter(...).values('pk')\
  .order_by('pk').distinct('pk')
).order_by('addr')

# This fails because *addr* is not field on the new queryset. 
# I could define a custom *BaseModel* buy there are so many models with other complex relations.
Here are my attempts to solve my problem:
```

## Copying annotations from one queryset to another

```py
annotations=queryset.query.annotations

Person.objects.annotate(**annotations)\
  .filter(
       pk__in=queryset.order_by('pk')\
         .distinct('pk').values('pk')
  ).order_by('addr')

# Failed because the annotations seemed to have been tightly coupled to the original queryset after their declaration
```

Comment: Can you post the code that you are talking about.

Comment: I have updated.

Comment: For clarity: `Person.objects.order_by('home__street', 'home__city')` doesn't give you the results that you want?

Answer (score 1):

> Get a of Person queryset ordered by the street, city combination in one string (Coalation)

I think you mean *concatenation* or *coalescing*, not *collation*. `Coalate` is not an ORM expression, but the syntax looks like you wanted [`Concat`](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/5.0/ref/models/database-functions/#concat). Try something like:

```py
from django.db.models import CharField, Value
from django.db.models.functions import Concat

queryset = (
    Person.objects
    .annotate(
        addr=Concat(
            'street', Value(' '), 'city', 
            output_field=CharField()
        )
    )
    .order_by('addr')
)
```

Comment: Thanks. I actually was referring to Concat. Thanks for the correction.  Let me update the question

Answer (score 0):

**1st method**

Advantages :-

1. Only one query
2. simplicity

Do it like below.

```
class Person(models.Model):
  name=models.CharField(...)
  home=models.ForeignKey(Home,...)
 

  def adress(self):
    adress = self.street + self.city
    return adress
```

```
queryset=Person.objects.filter(...).order_by('adress').distinct('pk')

Or

queryset=Person.objects.filter(adress='your_search_adress').order_by('adress').distinct('pk')
```

///////////////////////////////////////////////

**For
Copying annotations from one queryset to another**
(you can copy annotates, but
Annotated values become just the same as object properties after being annotated(that's what the annotation mean).
So,

```
annotations=queryset.query.annotations
```

Is not valid.
So, what you can do is,

**2nd method**

Disadvantages:-

1. use of loops, comprehensions
2. low simplicity

** Use,

1. **for loop**
2. **python comprehensions.**

Comment: Note that I am avoiding the use of properties on the model. The field has to be filtered on the queryset.

Comment: Can I ask why you avoid model properties ? ( def properties does not save on database. They only calculated opon query evaluation)

Comment: I was hoping not to involve python comprehension or loops but keep everything in sql. If all else fails, I'll resort to the suggestion.

Comment: Ok. Why avoid model def properties?

Comment: They are just sql. In python. But does not stored in db.

Comment: I wouldn't involve loops, comprehensions ether. That's why they are the second method. I would use 1st method.

Comment: I don't really  have an issue with Def properties, the main issue is addressing the sorting issue where I have to ignore duplicates. So a solution addressing sorting complex fields while avoiding duplicate results will be appreciated

Comment: That's my 1st method. It does that. Just use it. That's how django does this kind of things. And I wouldn't say this is very complex.

Comment: Look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1205375/filter-by-property). It's not possible to filter properties in Django 4.x. I don't know about 5.

Comment: Yes. But you asked about ordering. Not filtering.

Comment: You didn't try my answer. And you are trying to find out ay answer is possible without trying?

Comment: Oh i see. , the annotated felds are being used for both filtering and sorting. So perhaps that's where the confusion is

Comment: I haven't tried out ordering by the computed property yet. I will give you feedback

Comment: It would be more clear, if you tell us what you want achieve actually. What is the objective queryset?

Comment: As I earlier stated, I'm having duplicates when I order a queryset by a field/ fields on a foreign key. It so happens that those fields should be used for both filtering and ordering

Comment: You mean to filter queryset with same queryset?